# Oracle Net Configuration Assistant failed

Tags: database, linux, oracle, installation, oracle12c

After installing Oracle Linux 6:

```
uname -a
Linux ponos 2.6.39-400.109.1.el6uek.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jun 4 23:21:51 PDT 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

and making sure that all the pre-required packages are present, I downloaded "Oracle Database 12c Release 1 (12.1.0.1.0) for Linux x86-64", followed the pre-installation instructions and launched the installer.

The installer runs smoothly up to the "Execute Root Scripts" step.

During the "Oracle Database configuration", the "Oracle Net Configuration Assistant" throws error:

**[INS-20802] Oracle Net Configuration Assistant failed.**

The error log is empty:

```
-rw-rw----. 1 oracle oinstall 1197690 Jul  8 14:45 installActions2013-07-08_02-18-05PM.log
-rw-rw----. 1 oracle oinstall       0 Jul  8 14:30 oraInstall2013-07-08_02-18-05PM.err
-rw-rw----. 1 oracle oinstall     114 Jul  8 14:30 oraInstall2013-07-08_02-18-05PM.out
```

**Questions:**

1. Has anyone encountered the same problem and managed to resolve it?
2. Is this configuration essential to install/run the database?

Comment: 12C is a very new release.  Only a relative handful of people have downloaded and installed it, and they're mainly Oracle enthusiasts.  The chances of such people visiting a generalist programming site like SO is pretty small.  I suggest you try the Oracle Technet forums instead.  They have a whole forum dedicated to DB Installation problems: https://forums.oracle.com/community/developer/english/oracle_database/installation

Comment: are any core files created?

Answer (score 0):

Without closing the installer, try to do retry. It should work second time.